# How to add cache-control to a @RestController servlet path?

Tags: java, spring, http

I have a `servlet` to offer images resources via `spring`:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/thumbnails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getThumbnail(int id) {
    return service.find(id);
}
```

Resulting http headers: `Cache-control: "max-age=0"`.

Question: how can I control the cache header just for that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended as follows, which worked:

```
ResponseEntity.ok().lastModified(file.lastModified()).header("max-age", "86400");
```

I don't now why the approach with `CacheControl` class does not work.

Comment: Great...that is what I refereed to "Spring has support for that - ref API"

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can implement the check of the last modified, Spring has support for that - ref [API](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.HeadersBuilder.html)

Something like

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/thumbnails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getThumbnail(int id) {


    youeObject = service.find(id);
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(youeObject);
    builder.cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)).cachePrivate());
    return builder.build();

}
```

Comment: `package org.springframework.http.CacheControl` does not have `setMaxAge()` or `setPrivate()`, and `new CacheControl()` constructor is not visible?

Comment: I guess I mixed 2 things. Either use the Spring HTTPHeaders and JAX-WS cache control - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/CacheControl.html

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work. The cache control header remains as 0 age.

Comment: There is a bug in Spring Security 4.2.2 where Cache-Control is ignored: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4307

Answer (score 2):

I am using following:

```
public ResponseEntity getProducts(...) {
    ...
    return ResponseEntity.ok().cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES).cachePrivate()).body(productProxy);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
You can specify the cache's maxage by setMaxAge() of CacheControl class.
Also you can set it to public or private according to your requirement

**Follow the code snippets**

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/thumbnails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getThumbnail(int id) {
BodyBuilder builder = (BodyBuilder) ResponseEntity.ok();
CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
    cc.setMaxAge(64, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    cc.setPrivate(true);
     builder.cacheControl(cc);
    return builder.body(service.find(id));
    }
```

Comment: sorry, but why are you repeating the answer already given be @SheetalMohanSharma?